# Can I launch a File History backup from a script?

Tags: windows-10, script, file-history

I use Windows 10's File History for my backups on a drive that isn't always plugged in, so I have to launch the backup manually.

Is there a way to directly launch a File History backup from a script, instead of going in the Settings app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start File History backup on demand, you can use this command-line. Note that it's a undocumented switch and may not necessarily work in future builds.

> FhManageW -backupnow

Source: [How to Delete Older Versions of Files from File History Backup? » Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/delete-older-versions-files-file-history/)