# How to do automatic encrypted backups while minimizing maintenance?

Tags: windows, backup

I want to back up my most important data regularly, on an external USB HDD. The backups must be encrypted.

I tried Windows 10's File History, which has two problems :

- doesn't support encryption, forcing me to mount a VeraCrypt volume each time by entering its password, which can become quite tedious in the long run,
- doesn't have a practical "backup now" button, which means that after having mounted the VC volume, I have to go in "Start menu/Settings/Backup/More options" and click on "Backup now".

This process, while safe, is *really* not optimal.

How can I automate it while keeping my data secure ? I'm particularly interested in not entering the password, and having either a quick option to launch a backup at any time, or an option to launch a backup when I plug the drive in.

Using File History or VeraCrypt is absolutely not a requirement, I'm looking for a good general method to do encrypted backups on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose to use Windows's File History in a VeraCrypt volume, and put a script on my desktop named "Backup now", containing this command ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/1118503/can-i-launch-a-file-history-backup-from-a-script)) :

```
FhManageW -backupnow
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Crashplan (free) for exactly this purpose: [download here](https://store.crashplan.com/store/)

It allows automated backups to external drive and I also have another external drive in my friend's house for free offsite backups. All data is encrypted in transit and at rest.